# How to define a pair type in Idris that only holds certain combinations of values

Tags: idris, dependent-type

I'm trying to learn about dependent types in Idris by attempting something way out of my depth. Please bear with me if I make any silly mistakes.

Given the simple type

```
data Letter = A | B | C | D
```

I would like to define a type `LPair` that holds a pair of `Letter` such that only "neighboring" letters can be paired. For example, `B` can be paired with `A` or `C`, but not `D` or itself. It wraps around, so `A` and `D` are treated as neighbors.

In practice, given `x : Letter` and `y : Letter`,  `mklpair x y` would be equivalent to `mklpair y x`, but I'm not sure if that property can or should be reflected in the type.

What is the best way to go about making such a type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to create a subset of `(Letter, Letter)` which elements fulfill the predicate `(a, b : Letter) -> Either (Next a b) (Next b a)`, where `Next` is are just the neighbors to the right:

```
data Letter = A | B | C | D

data Next : Letter -> Letter -> Type where
  AB : Next A B
  BC : Next B C
  CD : Next C D
  DA : Next D A

Neighbour : Letter -> Letter -> Type
Neighbour a b = Either (Next a b) (Next b a)

LPair : Type
LPair = (p : (Letter, Letter) ** Neighbour (fst p) (snd p))

mklpair : (a : Letter) -> (b : Letter) -> {auto prf : Neighbour a b} -> LPair
mklpair a b {prf} = ((a, b) ** prf)
```

---

N.B.: This approach is nice and simple, but once you implement a function that decides if `a` and `b` are next to each other, you'll need around `(number of letters)^3` cases:

```
isNext : (a : Letter) -> (b : Letter) -> Dec (Next a b)
isNext A A = No nAA where
  nAA : Next A A -> Void
  nAA AB impossible
  nAA BC impossible
  nAA CD impossible
  nAA DA impossible
isNext A B = Yes AB
...
```

If you have a lot of letters and need a decision function, the usual approach is thus to map your data to a recursive type like `Nat`. Because of your modulo case (`Next D A`), you'd need a wrapper like:

```
data NextN : Nat -> Nat -> Nat -> Type where
  NextS : {auto prf :      (S a) `LTE` m}  -> NextN m a (S a) -- succ in mod m
  NextZ : {auto prf : Not ((S a) `LTE` m)} -> NextN m a Z     -- wrap around

LToN : Letter -> Nat
LToN A = 0
LToN B = 1
LToN C = 2
LToN D = 3

LNeighbour : Letter -> Letter -> Type
LNeighbour x y =
  let a = LToN x
      b = LToN y
  in Either (NextN 3 a b) (NextN 3 b a)

LNPair : Type
LNPair = (p : (Letter, Letter) ** LNeighbour (fst p) (snd p))

mklnpair : (a : Letter) -> (b : Letter) -> {auto prf : LNeighbour a b} -> LNPair
mklnpair a b {prf} = ((a, b) ** prf)
```

With `NextS` and `NextZ` you only have two cases you need to inspect instead one for each letter.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is a proof that the letters are neighbouring. So with your definition of neighbours:

```
data Letter = A | B | C | D

neighbours : Letter -> Letter -> Bool
neighbours A B = True
neighbours B A = True
neighbours B C = True
neighbours C B = True
neighbours C D = True
neighbours D A = True
neighbours A D = True
neighbours _ _ = False

data LPair : Type where
  MkLPair : (x : Letter) -> (y : Letter) -> {auto prf : neighbours x y = True} -> LPair
```

The `{}` make the `prf` argument implicit, while the `auto` tells Idris to figure it out.