# Constructing proofs for a decision function in Idris

Tags: proof, idris, theorem-proving

I am trying to create a decision function for a type representing two consecutive elements in a modular space.

(This code is derived [from this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50297361/5005318) to a previous question of mine.)

```
data PreceedsN : Nat -> Nat -> Nat -> Type where
    PreceedsS : {auto prf : S a `LT` m} -> PreceedsN m a (S a)
    PreceedsZ : {auto prf : S a = m} -> PreceedsN m a Z

doesPreceedN : (m : Nat) -> (a : Nat) -> (b : Nat) -> Dec (PreceedsN m a b)
doesPreceedN m a b with (S a `cmp` m)
    doesPreceedN (S a + S d) a b     | CmpLT d with (S a `decEq` b)
        doesPreceedN (S a + S d) a b | CmpLT d | Yes prf = Yes ?bIsSa
        doesPreceedN (S a + S d) a b | CmpLT d | No contra = No ?bNotSa
    doesPreceedN (S m) m b     | CmpEQ   with (b `decEq` 0)
        doesPreceedN (S m) m Z | CmpEQ | Yes prf = Yes PreceedsZ
        doesPreceedN (S m) m b | CmpEQ | No contra = No ?saIsmAndbIsNotZ
    doesPreceedN (S m) (m + (S d)) b | CmpGT d = No ?saCannotBeGTm
```

I've done my best, but I'm not knowledgable enough yet to construct the necessary proofs on my own, especially the proofs of contradiction. Could you walk me through how to fill one or more of the [holes](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#sect-holes) in the code above?

Also, if you use any handy tools, like `absurd`, `impossible`, or [tactics](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/reference/elaborator-reflection.html), could you explain how they work and the part they play in the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `prf`s in the `PreceedsN`-constructor needs a `LTE` proof (`LT a b` is just a synonym for `LTE (S a) b`), your first `cmp` just splits `S a`. Instead, you should directly get the `LTE` proof:

```
doesPreceedN m a b with (S (S a) `isLTE` m)
```

If you don't need to reuse all the variables, omitting the repetition in the `with` cases makes things a bit prettier. So to repeat your version with the `LTE`, we have:

```
  | (Yes lte) = case (decEq b (S a)) of
      Yes Refl => PreceedsS
      No notlte => No ?contra_notlte
  | (No notlte) with (decEq (S a) m)
    | Yes eq = case b of
      Z => Yes PreceedsZ
      (S b) => No ?contra_notZ
    | No noteq = No ?contra_noteq
```

In all these cases you need a to prove some `a -> Void`, so you can assume, you have that `a`. You can either create a lemma (your editor might have bindings for that) or use a lambda with a case split. For short functions like here, I favor the latter. For `?contra_notZ`:

```
No (\contra => case contra of prec => ?contra_notZ)
```

If you split on `prec`, you'd have:

```
No (\contra => case contra of PreceedsS => ?contra_notZ)
```

Inspecting the hole, you'll see that you have:

```
notlte : LTE (S (S b)) m -> Void
prf : LTE (S (S b)) m
```

`prf` is the implicit argument of `PreceedsS`, so to get it in scope, you can match against it:

```
No (\contra => case contra of (PreceedsS {prf}) => notlte prf)
```

`?contra_noteq` can be solved similiary.

The lambda for `?contra_notlte`:

```
No notlte => No (\contra => case contra of
  PreceedsS => ?contra_notlte_1
  PreceedsZ => ?contra_notlte_2)
```

Checking the types gives:

```
:t ?contra_notlte_1
notlte : (S a = S a) -> Void
:t ?contra_notlte_2
lte : LTE (S (S a)) m
prf : S a = m
```

`?contra_notlte_2` is the trickiest, because you can't just apply `notlte`. But you can see that after `lte : LTE (S m) m` should be false, so we create a function for it:

```
notLTE : Not (LTE (S n) n)
notLTE LTEZero impossible
notLTE (LTESucc lte) = notLTE lte
```

Now we have:

```
PreceedsZ {prf} => notLTE ?contra_notlte_2
?contra_notlte_2 : LTE (S n) n
```

I tried to replace the hole with `(rewrite prf in lte)`, but that didn't work, because the tactic didn't find the right property to rewrite. But we can be explicit about that:

```
PreceedsZ {prf} => notLTE (replace prf lte)

> Type mismatch between
        LTE (S (S a)) m
and
        P (S a)
```

So we set `P` explicitly by setting  `{P=(\x => LTE (S x) m)}`.

The result:

```
doesPreceedN : (m : Nat) -> (a : Nat) -> (b : Nat) -> Dec (PreceedsN m a b)
doesPreceedN m a b with (S (S a) `isLTE` m)
  | (Yes lte) = case (decEq b (S a)) of
    Yes Refl => Yes PreceedsS
    No notlte => No (\contra => case contra of
      PreceedsS => notlte Refl
      PreceedsZ {prf} => notLTE  (replace prf {P=(\x => LTE (S x) m)} lte))
  | (No notlte) with (decEq (S a) m)
    | Yes eq = case b of
      Z => Yes PreceedsZ
      (S b) => No (\contra => case contra of (PreceedsS {prf}) => notlte prf)
    | No noteq = No (\contra => case contra of 
        PreceedsS {prf} => notlte prf
        PreceedsZ {prf} => noteq prf)
```

---

`replace : (x = y) -> P x -> P y` just rewrites a part of a type. 
For example, with `(n + m = m + n)` we can replace the `n + m` part of `Vect (n + m) a` to `Vect (m + n) a`. Here `P=\to_replace => Vect to_replace a`, so `P` is just a function `Type -> Type`.

In `doesPreceedN` we needed to be explicit about `P`. Most of the time, `rewrite … in …` (a tactic) can find this `P` automatically and apply `replace`. `replace` on the other hand is just a simple function `:printdef replace`:

```
replace : (x = y) -> P x -> P y
replace Refl prf = prf
```

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding exactly how `rewrite` works. Could you show what the code would look like without that tactic?

Comment: Sorry; I meant `replace`.

Comment: `replace` isn't a tactic (`rewrite` is), but a short function. And there is no simpler way to rewrite this without `replace`, but I extended the answer with an explanation for them; hopefully, it helps!